# Unable to set RequestHeaders in HTTPServiceWrapper (actionscript 3)

Tags: actionscript, httprequest

I created an HTTPService using the Data Centric Development feature in Flash Builder 4. For some reason, I'm not able to set the requestheaders for an HTTP GET request. I've tried setting the headers object for the mx.rpc.http.Operation; but, it doesn't seem to work. Packet sniffers show that the requestheader isn't changed.

For example here's part of the gettour service:

```
 public class GetTourService extends _Super_GetTourService
  {
     /**
     * Override super.init() to provide any initialization customization if needed.
     */
    protected override function preInitializeService():void
    {
      super.preInitializeService();
      // Initialization customization goes here

      var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader( "Accept", "application/json");
      var headers:Array = new Array();
      headers.push(header);

      var o:Object = this._serviceControl.getOperation( "gettour");
      var operation:Operation = o as Operation;
      operation.headers = headers;
    }
}
```

However, packet sniffers show the Accept header to be "Accept: */*\r\n". In AIR I get a similar problem with the long list of default Accept values and can't set the Accept value to "application/json". What am I missing?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

EDITED: I found the answer this morning. Instead of

headers.push( header);

I used

headers[ "Accept"] = "/application/json";

This worked.

Comment: In my case I have `operation = new mx.rpc.http.Operation(null, "xxx");` `operation.headers = {Accept: "application/json"}`, but it doesn't work, any idea? I'm using the Data Grid in Flash Builder 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Since [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/Operation.html) for this is a bit vague I'm going to take a guess.  According to the docs, `headers` is an Object of custom headers, so passing it an indexed array is probably not going to work.  Try passing a defined Object instead:

```
operation.headers = {Accept:"application/json"};
```